# How to center a QLine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How does one center a vertical QLine in the center of my horizontal QLine to form a cross. My current implementation does not center the vertical line appropriately.

```
void crossWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, Qt::SolidLine));
    QLine originLine;
    int width = parent->width();
    int height = parent->height();

    originLine.setP1(QPoint(-width, 0));
    originLine.setP2(QPoint(width, 0));
    originLine.setLine( -(width / 2), 0, width / 2, 0);
    painter.drawLine(originLine);

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, Qt::DashLine));
    QLine originHLine;
    originHLine.setP1(QPoint(0, -height));
    originHLine.setP2(QPoint(0, height));
    originHLine.setLine(
        originLine.center().x(),
        originLine.center().y() - (height / 2) ,
        originLine.center().x(), 
        originLine.center().y() + (height / 2));
    painter.drawLine(originHLine);
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a cross you need the middle point of the canvas geometry...

your horizontal line (red one) will split your canvas into 2 identical shapes, 1 above the other.. so you need the middle point in the y axis.
analog to this, your vertical line (blue one) will split the canvas in t identical pieces, so you need the middle point in the x axis.

in qt you can draw a line by giving the origin and end point

so you need something like

```
drawLine(0, H/2, W, H/2);
```

and this will draw the red line for example...

see my ref picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why that complicated…

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class CrossWidget: public QWidget {

  public:
    CrossWidget(QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent)
    { }

    virtual ~CrossWidget() = default;

    CrossWidget(const CrossWidget&) = delete;
    CrossWidget& operator=(const CrossWidget&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent) override;
};

void CrossWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  const int w = width(), h = height();
  const int wH = w / 2, hH = h / 2;
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  qPainter.drawLine(0, hH, w, hH);
  qPainter.drawLine(wH, 0, wH, h);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  CrossWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot (GIF Animation)]

---

OP pointed out that the layout may shrink the `CrossWidget` that it makes it effectively invisible. To prevent this, the `sizeHint()` may be overloaded:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class CrossWidget: public QWidget {

  public:
    CrossWidget(QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent)
    { }

    virtual ~CrossWidget() = default;

    CrossWidget(const CrossWidget&) = delete;
    CrossWidget& operator=(const CrossWidget&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const override { return QSize(20, 20); }

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent) override;
};

void CrossWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  const int w = width(), h = height();
  const int wH = w / 2, hH = h / 2;
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  qPainter.drawLine(0, hH, w, hH);
  qPainter.drawLine(wH, 0, wH, h);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  QHBoxLayout qHBox;
  QLabel qLbl("A cross widget:");
  qHBox.addWidget(&qLbl, 1);
  CrossWidget qCross;
  qHBox.addWidget(&qCross);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qHBox);
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of the MCVE]

Comment: i like your animation!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yeah, but at latest after 30 seconds, you have to hide or close the window (or you won't be able to have any clear thought the rest of the day)... :-)

Comment: Thank you for implementation and animation.

Comment: If I was adding the widget to a layout, is overriding QWidget::sizeHint() required to show the widget? or does  QWidget::sizeHint() give an automatic height and width of the widget based on the layout dimensions?

Comment: @pennyBoy You are right: Without a size hint, the layout may shrink the widget to nothing. I will edit my answer... (The alternative would be to force the layout respectively that the `CrossWidget` may be given as much space as possible.)